# Trying to do SDV (Synthetic Data Vault) demo and getting error: TypeError: cannot astype a datetimelike from [datetime64[ns]] to [int32]

Tags: python, pandas, sdv

I'll start by saying I am NOT a Python developer.  But I have a need for synthetic data and was trying to use the Synthetic Data Vault (https://github.com/sdv-dev/SDV).

I have Python 3.7 installed (on Windows, I'm doing this right on my laptop for the moment while learning how it works).

python --version
Python 3.7.6

I was able to download the sdv package with pip and I can run the first several lines of demo code to load and view the metadata and demo tables).  However, when I get to these lines in the demo:

```
sdv = SDV()
sdv.fit(metadata, tables)
```

I get the following error:

TypeError: cannot astype a datetimelike from [datetime64[ns]] to [int32]

I have not modified any of the code from git at all and have not tried any of my own code.  I'm literally just trying to get the demo to work as described in the readme.  I just installed the package and am working through the first example.  Anybody try this and have the same problem?  Any ideas on what I can do to get passed this error?

The full stack trace is:

```
    sdv.fit(metadata, tables)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\tools\Python\3.7\lib\site-packages\sdv\sdv.py", line 69, in fit
    self.modeler.model_database(tables)
  File "C:\tools\Python\3.7\lib\site-packages\sdv\modeler.py", line 128, in model_database
    self.cpa(table_name, tables)
  File "C:\tools\Python\3.7\lib\site-packages\sdv\modeler.py", line 99, in cpa
    child_table = self.cpa(child_name, tables, child_key)
  File "C:\tools\Python\3.7\lib\site-packages\sdv\modeler.py", line 99, in cpa
    child_table = self.cpa(child_name, tables, child_key)
  File "C:\tools\Python\3.7\lib\site-packages\sdv\modeler.py", line 92, in cpa
    extended = self.metadata.transform(table_name, table)
  File "C:\tools\Python\3.7\lib\site-packages\sdv\metadata.py", line 477, in transform
    hyper_transformer.fit(data[fields])
  File "C:\tools\Python\3.7\lib\site-packages\rdt\hyper_transformer.py", line 128, in fit
    transformer.fit(column)
  File "C:\tools\Python\3.7\lib\site-packages\rdt\transformers\datetime.py", line 55, in fit
    transformed = self._transform(data)
  File "C:\tools\Python\3.7\lib\site-packages\rdt\transformers\datetime.py", line 40, in _transform
    integers = datetimes.astype(int).astype(float).values
  File "C:\tools\Python\3.7\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 5691, in astype
    **kwargs)
  File "C:\tools\Python\3.7\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 531, in astype
    return self.apply('astype', dtype=dtype, **kwargs)
  File "C:\tools\Python\3.7\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 395, in apply
    applied = getattr(b, f)(**kwargs)
  File "C:\tools\Python\3.7\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\blocks.py", line 534, in astype
    **kwargs)
  File "C:\tools\Python\3.7\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\blocks.py", line 2139, in _astype
    return super(DatetimeBlock, self)._astype(dtype=dtype, **kwargs)
  File "C:\tools\Python\3.7\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\blocks.py", line 633, in _astype
    values = astype_nansafe(values.ravel(), dtype, copy=True)
  File "C:\tools\Python\3.7\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\cast.py", line 646, in astype_nansafe
    to_dtype=dtype))
TypeError: cannot astype a datetimelike from [datetime64[ns]] to [int32]
```

Here is the full output of my session:

```
    from sdv import load_demo
     metadata, tables = load_demo(metadata=True)
     metadata.to_dict()
```

```
    {
      "tables": {
        "users": {
          "primary_key": "user_id",
          "fields": {
            "user_id": {
              "type": "id",
              "subtype": "integer"
            },
            "country": {
              "type": "categorical"
            },
            "gender": {
              "type": "categorical"
            },
            "age": {
              "type": "numerical",
              "subtype": "integer"
            }
          }
        },
        "sessions": {
          "primary_key": "session_id",
          "fields": {
            "session_id": {
              "type": "id",
              "subtype": "integer"
            },
            "user_id": {
              "ref": {
                "field": "user_id",
                "table": "users"
              },
              "type": "id",
              "subtype": "integer"
            },
            "device": {
              "type": "categorical"
            },
            "os": {
              "type": "categorical"
            }
          }
        },
        "transactions": {
          "primary_key": "transaction_id",
          "fields": {
            "transaction_id": {
              "type": "id",
              "subtype": "integer"
            },
            "session_id": {
              "ref": {
                "field": "session_id",
                "table": "sessions"
              },
              "type": "id",
              "subtype": "integer"
            },
            "timestamp": {
              "type": "datetime",
              "format": "%Y-%m-%d"
            },
            "amount": {
              "type": "numerical",
              "subtype": "float"
            },
            "approved": {
              "type": "boolean"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

```
    >>> tables
```

```
    {'users':    user_id country gender  age
    0        0     USA      M   34
    1        1      UK      F   23
    2        2      ES   None   44
    3        3      UK      M   22
    4        4     USA      F   54
    5        5      DE      M   57
    6        6      BG      F   45
    7        7      ES   None   41
    8        8      FR      F   23
    9        9      UK   None   30, 'sessions':    session_id  user_id  device       os
    0           0        0  mobile  android
    1           1        1  tablet      ios
    2           2        1  tablet  android
    3           3        2  mobile  android
    4           4        4  mobile      ios
    5           5        5  mobile  android
    6           6        6  mobile      ios
    7           7        6  tablet      ios
    8           8        6  mobile      ios
    9           9        8  tablet      ios, 'transactions':    transaction_id  session_id           timestamp  amount  approved
    0               0           0 2019-01-01 12:34:32   100.0      True
    1               1           0 2019-01-01 12:42:21    55.3      True
    2               2           1 2019-01-07 17:23:11    79.5      True
    3               3           3 2019-01-10 11:08:57   112.1     False
    4               4           5 2019-01-10 21:54:08   110.0     False
    5               5           5 2019-01-11 11:21:20    76.3      True
    6               6           7 2019-01-22 14:44:10    89.5      True
    7               7           8 2019-01-23 10:14:09   132.1     False
    8               8           9 2019-01-27 16:09:17    68.0      True
    9               9           9 2019-01-29 12:10:48    99.9      True}
```

```
    metadata.visualize()
```

```
<graphviz.dot.Digraph object at 0x00000196E8755488>
```

```
     from sdv import SDV
     sdv = SDV()
     sdv.fit(metadata, tables)
```

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\tools\Python\3.7\lib\site-packages\sdv\sdv.py", line 69, in fit
        self.modeler.model_database(tables)
      File "C:\tools\Python\3.7\lib\site-packages\sdv\modeler.py", line 128, in model_database
        self.cpa(table_name, tables)
      File "C:\tools\Python\3.7\lib\site-packages\sdv\modeler.py", line 99, in cpa
        child_table = self.cpa(child_name, tables, child_key)
      File "C:\tools\Python\3.7\lib\site-packages\sdv\modeler.py", line 99, in cpa
        child_table = self.cpa(child_name, tables, child_key)
      File "C:\tools\Python\3.7\lib\site-packages\sdv\modeler.py", line 92, in cpa
        extended = self.metadata.transform(table_name, table)
      File "C:\tools\Python\3.7\lib\site-packages\sdv\metadata.py", line 477, in transform
        hyper_transformer.fit(data[fields])
      File "C:\tools\Python\3.7\lib\site-packages\rdt\hyper_transformer.py", line 128, in fit
        transformer.fit(column)
      File "C:\tools\Python\3.7\lib\site-packages\rdt\transformers\datetime.py", line 55, in fit
        transformed = self._transform(data)
      File "C:\tools\Python\3.7\lib\site-packages\rdt\transformers\datetime.py", line 40, in _transform
        integers = datetimes.astype(int).astype(float).values
      File "C:\tools\Python\3.7\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 5691, in astype
        **kwargs)
      File "C:\tools\Python\3.7\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 531, in astype
        return self.apply('astype', dtype=dtype, **kwargs)
      File "C:\tools\Python\3.7\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 395, in apply
        applied = getattr(b, f)(**kwargs)
      File "C:\tools\Python\3.7\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\blocks.py", line 534, in astype
        **kwargs)
      File "C:\tools\Python\3.7\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\blocks.py", line 2139, in _astype
        return super(DatetimeBlock, self)._astype(dtype=dtype, **kwargs)
      File "C:\tools\Python\3.7\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\blocks.py", line 633, in _astype
        values = astype_nansafe(values.ravel(), dtype, copy=True)
      File "C:\tools\Python\3.7\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\cast.py", line 646, in astype_nansafe
        to_dtype=dtype))
    TypeError: cannot astype a datetimelike from [datetime64[ns]] to [int32]
```

Answer (score -1):

Actually, I found a solution - not being a Python developer, not sure if it's the best solution but it cleared up the error.

In the datetime.py code on line 41, I changed:

```
integers = datetimes.astype(int).astype(float).values
```

to

```
integers = datetimes.astype(np.int64).astype(float).values
```

I would assume though, there's a way to resolve this without changing the projects code (meaning this is not my code, this is the package I downloaded), but I'm able to continue my research now.